# ENOENT, no such file or directory only on Android 6.0 marshmallow

Tags: android, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow, jxcore

When I try to run a simple cordova project with an extension called jxcore for running node.js app on ios and android I get the following error. This only appears on android 6.0, in android 5.0 and iOS everything works.

[image]

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Is there a hard-coded `/data/data/com.gude_app.workshop/...` path anywhere in your source?

Comment: no, that path is generated automatically

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: It's already fixed on github https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova/issues/87#event-446903022

Comment: do you allow permission on android M for your app when runtime?

Answer (score 0):

JXcore-cordova 0.0.8 has this fixed and supports Android M. See the [commit](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova/commit/a94bb7f3c460bd3f80da75bb7b52754068583472) for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cordova 5.0.0 w/support for Android Marshmallow Just released.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/09/cordova-android-5.0.0.html

Unclear if it will fix your issue.